# Why am I getting negative value for the Dunn Index when I use Cosine Similarity?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, distance, cosine-similarity

I clustered normalized data using k-means. I used different similarity matrices like Euclidean, Manhattan and Cosine, and got a negative value for the Dunn Index when I used Cosine similarity. I have read that the value of the Dunn Index ranges from 0 to infinity. Is this correct to use Cosine Similarity to compute the Dunn index?

I have used [this implementation of Dunn Index](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27859-dunn-s-index).

Comment: Code downloaded / copied from the internet often does not work. Did you verify its correctness?

Comment: It worked well with other similarity matrices.

Comment: If you check the comments on that code, people don't always get good results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euclidean and Manhattan are distances. They can be used to measure similarity, but they satisfy the requirements for a distance. Most importantly, a negative distance doesn’t exist. 0 means identical, and the larger the value, the less similar they are.

Cosine similarity is defined as the cosine of the angle between two vectors. Two parallel vectors have a similarity of 1, and the larger the difference in angle, the lower the similarity. If the two vectors are opposite, the cosine similarity is -1.

Thus, cosine similarity is not a distance. And therefore you cannot use it where a distance is required, such as computing the Dunn Index.